# Swift support for google plus

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, google-plus

Does Google support the Google Plus SDK for iOS in the Swift language?

If possible, provide me some reference regarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using cocoa pods and the [this approach](https://medium.com/swift-programming/google-in-swift-a0943352dfe9), make sure you use

```
\#import <</>googleplus_ios_sdk/GooglePlus.h</>>
```

instead of

```
\#import <</>googleplus-ios-sdk/GooglePlus.h</>>
```

This took hours to figure out...

Answer (score 1):

Google+ SDK is written in Objective-C. You can refer to the Apple ebook 'Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C' to find out how to use the Objective-C framework from Swift. You can access the book via iBooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference link.
https://medium.com/swift-programming/google-in-swift-a0943352dfe9

i work sample in github,it can rum.
https://github.com/masouk/IOS_in_SWIFT_sample/tree/master/GooglePlusTest